# Can I wear the Law, Blighted Beak and the Bruisers Bandanna?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I don't know if I want the blighted beak or not yet. it all depends on whether I can wear it with the bruiser bandanna and the law. Am I able to wear the law, bandanna and the law hat in tf2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Equipping multiple cosmetic items is based on the items' equip regions. If two items are equipped in the same region (or certain overlapping regions), they cannot be worn together. For more information, check [this wiki page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Equip_region).

*The Law* is equipped in the head region, the *Blighted Beak* is equipped in the face region, and the *Bruiser's bandana* is equipped in the beard region. This means you can wear all three at the same time. This would, however, use up all your cosmetic slots.